# Add new variable to defined struct

Tags: solidity, struct, state-variable

Is it possible to create a new variable/key -with its corresponding value- for an already defined Struct?

Kind of like objects in JS.

```js
struct MyStruct {   //defined elsewhere in SomeLib
   uint num;
   uint num2;
}


function setNewVar() public {
   MyStruct storage x = SomeLib.getX();  
   x.num3 = 42;   //----> is something like this possible?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a new variable/key -with its corresponding
> value- for an already defined Struct?

No. the struct is defined at compilation time, and its definition will never change after that.

You might be able to hack around a solution using mappings though...

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    
    struct MyStruct {
      uint256 a;
      mapping(string => uint256) properties;
    }
    
    MyStruct testStruct;
    
    function testFunction() public {
        testStruct.properties['b'] = 100;
    }

}
```

But don't do that, it implies that you define the struct and it would just be a very bad practice to add "members" to a struct that way, don't do it.